# getting only instance of human entries in wikidata

Tags: wikidata

Is there a way to get only higher confidence wikidata entries?

For example how do I tell that this is not an article about a person: 
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q19069838&language=en&limit=1

The instanceof attribute (P31) links to human (Q5).

This article is clearly not about the human but the memo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem with data: sometimes it's wrong, and as it's expected not to be, there is no way to work around, other than

- Fixing it ([I did it for Q19069838](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q19069838&diff=474097377&oldid=413902933))
- Training a program to detect this kind of errors for you, but then, please use it to fix those errors ;) Machine learning is currently being used as a way to [detect vandalism in Wikidata](https://groups.uni-paderborn.de/fg-engels/publications_pdfs/Konferenzbeitraege/heindorf2016_CIKM.pdf), I hope it will be further developed to address the kind of issue you encountered.